# iOS development - uitableview with infinite levels

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have XML data in a tree structure that has an variable depth.  Sometimes the data feed can be 50 levels deep, other times it will be 5 levels deep.

Which iOS UI component should I use for the view?  I saw uitableview, but it seems to only support 1 level of the tree before printing the leaf nodes.   Is there another UI component i'm supposed to consider?  If not, what should I do?

Comment: A UITableView is generally used for displaying hierarchical information. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html 

"An instance of UITableView (or simply, a table view) is a means for displaying and editing hierarchical lists of information"

Comment: Just a note - it "shows 1 level ... before printing leaf nodes", but remember, those "leaf nodes" can be instances of UITableView themselves (likely the *same* instance configured differently) allowing an infinite (if somewhat painful) navigation of depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for the iPhone, I would definitely suggest the standard UINavigationViewController with UITableView's at each level.  This is the standard iPhone way of dealing with hierarchy.

On iPad, there is an equivalent with the pop over (or side nav).  This is ok -- and you could use that.

If this is the main focus of your app, you might want to do something custom that takes advantage of the larger screen.